# What are the components of a rocket launch complex?

Tags: launchpad

What components are needed for a rocket launch pad besides the following?

- Tanks for Fuel and Water
- Lightning protection rods
- Hangar
- Launch Pad
- Duct
- Tracking Facility

Is there a good resource to estimate the costs of each?

Comment: Tanks for the oxidizer are also needed. Pumps, tubes and hoses for tanking.

Comment: Is this dedicated to one particular design of launch vehicle, or would it have to accomodate many sizes and and a variety of propellants? Does it include facilities for assembling the rockets, or can that be separate? What about offices and equipment for the staff and launch control?

Comment: There are a lot of rockets using different fuel/oxidizer combinations for first and second stage. A satellite or space probe as payload often uses another hygolic fuel/oxidizer.

Comment: To get you started: the new ELA4 launch pad being built for Ariane 6 is budgeted at $200M. http://www.eiffage.com/files/live/sites/eiffage/files/pdf/CP%20ELA4%20-%20Ariane%20GB.pdf

Comment: @uhoh Preferably the most common facilities. No, not for assembling rockets (though I would like to know the cost of building an end-to-end facility for rocket manufacturing), but the staff and launch control buildings are factored in.

Comment: payload handling and integration