# Are there any references about rocket Launchapd Design?

Tags: launch-site, launchpad

I am trying to figure out all the systems/structures/services that would be required to support rocket launches. Are there any references that describe this information? Essentially, I want to have the concept as if I were starting from scratch and I only have the land, with the objective of launching commercial communication satellites.

Is there such a reference?

Comment: *Different* but related questions, there may be some helpful resources cited: [Launch pad design considerations](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29591/12102) as well as [What are the components of a rocket launch complex?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24552/12102) and also [Launchpad platform structural design](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24379/12102)

Answer (score 3):

The first place to look for that kind of information is [NASA's Technical Reports Server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/). 
I did some searching there, but I found no high-level overview. There's lots of detailed information, e.g. [this report on acoustic models](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20120015223&hterms=launch%20pad%20design%20overview&qs=Ntx%3Dmode%2520matchallpartial%26Ntk%3DAll%26N%3D0%26No%3D0%26Ntt%3D%2522launch%2520pad%2522%2520design%2520overview).

So your starting point may have to be something like the [Wikipedia article on launch pads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_pad), and look up the more detailed info in the NTRS.

A Web search for "Launch pad design handbook" didn't turn up any results either.

Many aspects of launch pad design depend on the rocket you want to launch. E.g.:

- for a large launcher, you may need a water deluge system to protect the pad. for small launchers this is not necessary
- the rocket propellants determine what fueling facilities you need on the pad: which propellants and how much of each. Locations of the fueling ports on the rocket (at ground level or high up). Cryogenic fuels or storable propellants. etc.
- the preparation process for the rocket determines which facilities you need on the pad. The Shuttle launch pads were really elaborate, with a structure that allowed access to the payload bay so satellites could be loaded into the bay while the stack sat on the pad. Others are much simpler. If a rocket has to be integrated while vertical, you need a tall building next to the pad, and means to either move the rocket while it's vertical or move the building.